# show and hide logos and banners

Tags: image, hide, show

In my site,there is three positions to show ad logos with link .I can add the logos and set the time required to show the logos in front page(Eg 10 sec for a logo).In each position ,the time may be different.(For eg I can set 20 sec for an image to display in position1 ) After time ,the images must hide.How can I implement this functionality in home page. Remember All settings for the images are stored in database.

Please help me....
Kirku

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to hide the image after a given amount of time using the `setTimeout` function. When the given amount of time has passed, you can change the style of the required image to `display:none`.

As the images can be displayed for different amounts of time, I would suggest giving each image a unique `id` (perhaps they already have a unique ID in your database table) which can then be used to identify that image in your JavaScript.